# how can I get 2 alphabet 7 numeric 1 alphabet format for a string in regex in .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

example for the format is aa1231231c

Answer (score 6):

Well that looks like:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}[a-zA-Z]
```

to me. Of course it depends on what you mean by "alphabet" and "numeric" - the above only deals with ASCII letters and digits, with no accents, no other types of digits etc. You

Note that there are alternative approaches such as using `\d` for "any digit" and `\p{L}` to match "any letter"; if you really only *want* the ASCII letters and digits though, I'd use the above to make it obvious exactly what's allowed.

You can either match that as the whole string in code, or use `^` and `$` to force it in the expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}[a-zA-Z]$
```

That will prevent your pattern being found in the middle of other text.

Comment: I think that the use of `\p{L}` should be thought very much. It's like using `\d` without knowing its real meaning. Using `\p{L}` you are "skipping" all the "combinable" marks (the `\p{M}`) (http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html ). so it should be `(\p{L}\p{M}*)`.

Comment: @xanatos: Possibly. It depends on the context - but yes, it's something that should be done with thought.

Answer (score 2):

Are you validating an entire string?

```
Regex myPattern = new Regex(@"^[a-z]{2}\d{7}[a-z]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

No?

```
Regex myPattern = new Regex(@"[a-z]{2}\d{7}[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: You'll stop using `\d` the day a script-kiddie will use a `१` (DEVANAGARI DIGIT ONE (it's upper case because in the unicode tables they love upper case) that will crash your int.Parse (that souldn't have crashed becaue you were parsing digits)